# What is the proper way to create a dictionary of dictionaries using late binding in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries in vba (Excel). When I assign my child dictionary to the parent, it seems like it's adding a pointer instead of copying the dictionary.

```
Sub DictionaryTest()
    Dim dicParent As Object
    Set dicParent = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim dicChild As Object
    Set dicChild = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 0 To 1 ' Create 2 entries in parent
        dicChild.RemoveAll ' Clear the child dictionary
        
        dicChild.Add "Child Key 1", "Child Item = " & i
        
        dicParent.Add "Parent Key " & i, dicChild
        
        Debug.Print _
           "Inside Loop:", _
           dicParent.Keys()(i), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Keys()(0), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Items()(0)
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dicParent.Count - 1
        Debug.Print _
           "Outside Loop:", _
           dicParent.Keys()(i), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Keys()(0), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Items()(0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I end up with a dictionary with all items set to the last loop:

```
Inside Loop:  Parent Key 0  Child Key 1   Child Item = 0
Inside Loop:  Parent Key 1  Child Key 1   Child Item = 1

Outside Loop: Parent Key 0  Child Key 1   Child Item = 1
Outside Loop: Parent Key 1  Child Key 1   Child Item = 1
```

What is the proper way to prevent this?

Comment: You only have 1 child dictionary object, that you wipe at each iteration. If you intend to have 1 child per parent, you need to *create 1 child per parent*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were early binding, the child dictionary would be set as a new dictionary inside the loop using `Set dicChild = New Dictionary`. In late binding, the child is set as a new dictionary using `Set dicChild = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

In other words, move the child dictionary definition inside the loop:

```
Sub DictionaryTest()
    Dim dicParent As Object
    Set dicParent = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim dicChild As Object
    
    For i = 0 To 1 ' Create 10 entries in parent
        Set dicChild = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        dicChild.Add "Child Key 1", "Child Item = " & i
        
        dicParent.Add "Parent Key " & i, dicChild
        
        Debug.Print _
           "Inside Loop:", _
           dicParent.Keys()(i), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Keys()(0), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Items()(0)
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dicParent.Count - 1
        Debug.Print _
           "Outside Loop:", _
           dicParent.Keys()(i), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Keys()(0), _
           dicParent.Items()(i).Items()(0) dicParent.Items()(i).Items()(0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The result is now correct:

```
Inside Loop:  Parent Key 0  Child Key 1   Child Item = 0
Inside Loop:  Parent Key 1  Child Key 1   Child Item = 1

Outside Loop: Parent Key 0  Child Key 1   Child Item = 0
Outside Loop: Parent Key 1  Child Key 1   Child Item = 1
```

Comment: Or create a custom object (class) that will be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Definitely consider making a custom data type for this. `thing()(i).Items()(0)` is a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Normally I would reference it as `Parent.Item(i).Key(j)` and `Parent.Item(i).Item(j)`. I used the `Parent.Items()(i).Items()(j)` format in the post because it's the same inside and outside the loop. I do agree that `.Keys()(i)` and `.Items()(i)` is a nightmare.